# How to make a .dmg file?

Tags: macos, finder, dmg

I know how to make a .dmg file but I do not know how developers (Mostly games) create a window where there is the software file and sometimes theres a readme file. When I create, It shows just a normal finder window not like with custom background or where you can drag the folder anywhere on the finder window. How am I suppose to make that? I making a game and I really want to make it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [DropDMG](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/)

I use and recommend DropDMG since it has many [features](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/features) that make it useful for sharing software such as scripting the building of a DMG file directly from my CI server when I promote a build using the included [CLI tool `dropdmg`](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/manual-ah/command-line-tool).

[image: Configurations Window]

<sup>Above: Many options for [configuring a DMG file](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/manual-ah/configurations), including [layouts](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/manual-ah/layout.html) and showing a [license](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/manual-ah/license.html) when opening the DMG.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Most developers create dmg files from command line because they need to integrate to their  build process. There is a nice post on SO may help you: [How do I create a nice-looking DMG for Mac OS X using command-line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882/how-do-i-create-a-nice-looking-dmg-for-mac-os-x-using-command-line-tools), This post mentioned many scripts/tools you can use to create you dmg file.